# What is the most effective way to get elements of RDD in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I need to get values of two columns of a dataframe converted to RDD.

The first solution I have thought is that

- First convert the RDD to List of Row `RDD.collect()`
- then for each element of List, get values by using `Row[i].getInt(column_index)`

this solution works fine with small and medium size of data. But in large one, I got `over memory`.

My temporary solution is that I only create newRDD which contains only two Columns instead all columns. And then, apply my solution above, this may reduce most of needed memory.

Current implementation is like this:

```
Row[] rows = sparkDataFrame.collect();
for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { //about 50 million rows
  int yTrue = rows[i].getInt(0);
  int yPredict = rows[i].getInt(1);
}
```

Could you help me to improve my solution, or suggest me other solutions!

Thanks!

ps: I'm a new spark's user!

Answer (score 0):

First you convert your big RDD into Dataframe and than directly you can select whatever columns you require.

```
// Create the DataFrame
DataFrame df = sqlContext.jsonFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.json");

// Select only the "name" column
df.select(df.col("name"), df.col("age")).show();
```

For more detail you can follow this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes)

Comment: U mean, create new df is more effective than create new RDD?

Comment: how about using "foreach" - my friend recommendation!

Comment: Its depend on your use-case, if you want more transformation like some aggregation or you want different different columns as in separate RDDs then you can `DataFrame`.


Or otherwise you can use map function to extract those columns from that RDD then collect it.